# read value from the next line of a match

Tags: python

I am trying to get the lattice parameter from a file, like 
sysname:

```
lattice parameter A  [a.u.] 
    8.069100000000
```

And I have to grab the number from the next line of the match. I have written the script as:

```
   with open(sysname, "r") as sysinp:
        for line in sysinp:
            if line.startswith("lattice parameter A"):
                next(sysinp)
                print(line.strip())
```

I was expecting `next()` to go to the next line, which is not happening unfortunately. `print()` is printing the matching line.

What I am doing wring here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
line = next(sysinp)
```

In your code you don't use the line read by `next()` but still use the
previous line from the `for` loop, i.e. the matching line.

The whole code snippet:

```
with open(sysname, "r") as sysinp:
    for line in sysinp:
        if line.startswith("lattice parameter A"):
            line = next(sysinp)
            print(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 2):

You have gotten the next line, but you haven't assigned anything to it.  You need to use `line = next(sysinp)` instead of just `next(sysinp)`.  You could also just use `print(next(sysinp).strip())` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the next line:

```
with open(sysname, "r") as sysinp:
    for line in sysinp:
        if line.startswith("lattice parameter A"):
            try:
                line = next(sysinp)
                print(line.strip())
            except StopIteration:
                # handle the case where there is no next line
```